# Print column content a if column content b != 0

Tags: python, pandas, printing, is-empty

I have a similar dataframe to this one:

| Names | abandoned_calls | total_calls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kerstin | 0 | 50 |
| Cathlyn | 0 | 53 |
| James | 1 | 53 |
| Nathaniel | 0 | 53 |
| Patrick | 1 | 53 |
| Lucy | 0 | 53 |

What I am trying to get is the names of the call handlers that had an abandoned call, I have tried the following code:

```
for content in df["abandoned_calls"] != 0:
   print(df["Names"])
```

However, I get:

```
KeyError: 'Names'
```

I get the same error if I try:

```
for content in df[abandoned_calls].notnull:
   print(df[Names])
```

The ideal response will be simply:

```
James
Patrick
```

I have also tried:

```
if pd.notnull(df["abandoned_calls"]):
        print(df["Names"])
```

But I get this:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.loc[df['abandoned_calls'] != 0, 'Names']
```

Result:

```
2      James
4    Patrick
Name: Names, dtype: object
```